# convert javascript date to c# datetime

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

I am trying to convert javascript date to c# datetime

## JavaScript Code

```
var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();        
    var month = date.getMonth();    
    var year = date.getFullYear();  
    var hour = date.getHours();     
    var minute = date.getMinutes(); 
    var second = date.getSeconds(); 

    // After this construct a string with the above results as below
    var JSDateString = year+ "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;
```

## C# Code

```
var JSDateString = "2016-04-02 17:15:45";  // I receive date string via Ajax call in this format

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(JSDateString , "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I get invalid datetime format exception. I researched other options in internet but I didn't find any specific answer on how to convert JavaScript datetime to C# datetime.

Comment: should convert it to timestamp

Comment: @Steve yes, and also have a eye in the possible diference in timezones between client and server in this case.

Comment: @r1verside timestamp is timezone safe. unless you want the server time instead of local time

Comment: @Steve timestamp is UTC. But the problem is JavaScript does not know how to handle timezone so if you're displaying dates in a different timezone than the browser timezone, it will give you an incorrect timestamp, because it will not be UTC.

Comment: @r1verside op is trying to parse the datetime sent from js time to c# time.

Answer (score 3):

`mm` is for minutes, you want `MM` for month:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(JSDateString , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help with the JavaScript side:

```
function getDate() {
  var date = new Date(),
    year = date.getFullYear(),
    month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(),
    formatedMonth = (month.length === 1) ? ("0" + month) : month,
    day = date.getDate().toString(),
    formatedDay = (day.length === 1) ? ("0" + day) : day,
    hour = date.getHours().toString(),
    formatedHour = (hour.length === 1) ? ("0" + hour) : hour,
    minute = date.getMinutes().toString(),
    formatedMinute = (minute.length === 1) ? ("0" + minute) : minute,
    second = date.getSeconds().toString(),
    formatedSecond = (second.length === 1) ? ("0" + second) : second;
  return year + "-" + formatedMonth + "-" + formatedDay + " " + formatedHour + ':' + formatedMinute + ':' + formatedSecond;
};
```

View a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kpduncan/de8j318k/

I had too do something like this when I building an application due to not being allowed to add thrid party JS and needing support back to IE8.

Comment: Thanks. Very useful for trailing 0s for parsing on the C# side (fiddle is gone though)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), `mm` is for minutes (00 - 59) whereas `MM` is for the month (01 - 12).

```
var JSDateString = "2016-04-02 17:15:45";
var formatCode = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(JSDateString , formatCode, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can see that `mm` is for minutes because you already use it in your `HH:mm:ss`.